# Gitlab CI/CD Artifact permissions issue

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I wrote a little go binary to calculate the version of any of my projects and use this in a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline stage. I then artifact the output to be consumed by other stages. However, I run the generate version stage with a distroless image as `USER 65532:65532`. When I then attempt to access this file in subsequent stages, i get a permission denied. How can i fix this?

Comment: Add your .gitlab-ci.yml and the gitlab-runner configuration to the question. Which executor are you using? Under which user do you execute the gitlab-runner?

Comment: I resolved the issue, I had untracked: true in the artifacts stage, and also the generated file in the .gitignore file. I removed both and now we are good! :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with semantic-versioning. Removing the tag...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, I had untracked: true in the artifacts stage, and also the generated file in the .gitignore file. I removed both and now we are good! :)

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you show that from .gitlab-ci.yml file in question and answer to an interested reader can better evaluate if they can benefit from the same change. Also leaving some references to the docs can be helpful, too.